# Sql query to insert data from one table to another and set 'status ' column of destination table to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am creating procedure to copy some column from one table and set the 'Status' column to 1 but it's not working can any one help me? thanks in adavance ... i have tried this....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Psettemp]
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tblEmailToClient
                  (id,
                   clientName,
                   clientInfoOrgName,
                   clientInfoEmail,
                   RemainingDays)
      (SELECT a.clientinfoid                            AS clientId,
              ( client_FullName )                       AS client,
              client_info_orgname,
              client_info_email,
              Datediff(day, Getdate(), WarrentyExpDate) AS RemainingDays
       FROM   tblSales b
              JOIN tblclient_info a
                ON b.client_id = a.clientinfoid
       WHERE  Datediff(day, Getdate(), WarrentyExpDate) = 7
               OR Datediff(day, Getdate(), WarrentyExpDate) = 0)
  END
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable

Comment: *What* is not working? Are you getting a syntax error? Then what error message do you get? Or are too many / too few rows inserted? Or are the values incorrect?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the data from 2nd table is inserted but how can i set column namely 'status' =1 after insertion of each row

Comment: @it'sME Status? in which table? and what is the dependency of status with current query..

Comment: @AmneshGoel 
 
'Status' column in destination table , which should be set to 1 after copying each row from the 2nd table –

Comment: @it'sME Great. Destination table, second table.. these jargon doesn't make any sense in this context..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set a constant (status = 1) in each inserted record, simply add the literal value to your select statement.

```
insert into tblemailtoclient
(
  id,
  clientname,
  clientinfoorgname,
  clientinfoemail,
  remainingdays,
  status
)
(
  select  
    ci.clientinfoid, 
    ci.client_fullname,
    ci.client_info_orgname ,
    ci.client_info_email ,
    datediff(day, getdate(), s.warrentyexpdate),
    1
  from tblsales s 
  join tblclient_info ci on s.client_id = ci.clientinfoid 
  where datediff(day, getdate(), s.warrentyexpdate) in (0,7)
);
```

I've changed your alias names for readability. Always use meaningful alias names such as s for sales, rather than a, b, c, ...

I've also added the alias to all columns in the select statement, so one knows were the columns come from. You should make this a habit.

At last I changed your `OR` clause to `IN`, which is more readable. And I removed the unnecessary column aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PsetTemp]
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tblEmailToClient(
          id,
          clientName,
          clientInfoOrgName,
          clientInfoEmail,
          RemainingDays,
          status)
  SELECT a.clientinfoid AS clientId,
          client_FullName AS client,
          client_info_orgname,
          client_info_email,
          DATEDIFF(DAY,getdate(), WarrentyExpDate) AS RemainingDays,
          1 AS Status
   FROM tblSales b
   JOIN tblclient_info a 
     ON b.client_id=a.clientinfoid
   WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,getdate(),WarrentyExpDate) =7
     OR DATEDIFF(DAY,getdate(),WarrentyExpDate) =0
 END
```

Comment: the data from 2nd table is inserted but how can i set column namely 'status' =1 after insertion of each row

Comment: @it'sME `Status` in which table?

Comment: 'Status' column in destination table , which should be set to 1 after copying each row from the 2nd table

Comment: @See my answer, I set status column to 1